# How to move from one source block to another, in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, commands, motion

Is there a key-binding, command, or even evil extension for Emacs, so that I can move from one source block to another?

For example,`org-forward-heading-same-level`, which is bound in my system to `C-j`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is, run `M-x org-babel-next-src-block`. The default keybindings for this function are `C-c C-v C-n` and `C-c C-v n`.

See also the subsection [Key bindings and Useful Functions](https://orgmode.org/manual/Key-bindings-and-Useful-Functions.html#Key-bindings-and-Useful-Functions) in the orgmode manual.

Comment: And just plain `n` if you're on the header (`#+BEGIN`) line. Maybe `speedkeys` needs to be enabled for this?